# Chain Certificate Open SSL PFX

Tags: ssl, openssl, pfx

im trying to create a chain certificate via openssl to create a chain certificate
That's the outcome I need to get

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = XX, ST = State , L = City, O = Provider, CN = domain.com
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = GeoTrust TLS RSA CA G1
 1 s:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = GeoTrust TLS RSA CA G1
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root G2
 2 s:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root G2
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root G2
```

But the outcome i receive is:

```
0 s:C = XX, ST = State, L = City, O = Provider, CN = domain.com
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = GeoTrust TLS RSA CA G1
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Feb 18 00:00:00 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Mar 14 23:59:59 2023 GMT
 1 s:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = GeoTrust TLS RSA CA G1
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root G2
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Nov  2 12:23:37 2017 GMT; NotAfter: Nov  2 12:23:37 2027 GMT
```

In the outcome i want to get is not included rsa encryption but it's not important i have just the .key what i know how to include.

The files what i have are:

Root.crt

Intermediate.crt

Domain.crt

AS.key

I was able to only create a 2 part chain and i need to create a 3 part chain node.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you 'need' the server to transmit the root? **It just wastes bandwidth** and slows your connections; no correct client will trust differently because the root is transmitted, because any trust anchor must be local (and Digicert G2 should be). To be wasteful, your root.crt file presumably contains _some_ root but you'll have to look at the contents to determine if it's the _correct_ root and if not replace it, and include the (correct) file in `openssl pkcs12 -export -in` (or stdin) or `-certfile`. But this is not programming or development and is offtopic for SO.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 unfortunately it's not my idea to make it like this. It's a requirement, that I need to do, however could not find specific solution for this.